# Filtrar registros por mês e ano no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, data

Tenho um formulário com um campo do tipo `month`, que envia um valor no formato `Y-m` para o meu controller. Como faço pra buscar os registros do mes e ano selecionado?

Estou usando [l5-repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)

Fiz da seguinte forma, mas não funciona:

```
$date = Input::get('date');
$type = Input::get('type');

$values = $this->repository->findWhere(['type' => $type, 'date' => $date]);
```

Da o seguinte erro:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 761: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid
>   datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date:
>   "2016-09" (SQL: select * from "values" where "type" = Receita and
>   "date" = 2016-09)

Eu já imaginava que fosse dar esse erro, mas não sei como fazer funcionar. Alguém da uma luz?

Estou usando banco de dados Postgres e o campo **date** está no formato `date` mesmo.

Comment: Apenas uma pergunta fora do escopo do tópico: porquê você está usando esse repository ?

Comment: Então @PeterParker sinceramente não saberia te explicar direito pq ainda to estudando isso em um curso, mas ele serve pra abstrair a camada de dados. Ainda não fiz nada muito grande, mas pelo que entendi fica mais facil de manter a aplicação assim, não lidando com o model diretamente no controller. Desculpe não saber explicar direito =/

Comment: Na verdade tem um jeito [mais simples](https://wallacemaxters.com.br/blog/2021/02/23/como-pesquisar-por-mes-ou-ano-no-laravel). Basta utilizar `whereYear` e `whereMonth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por ser um campo do tipo `date`, você pode formatar a data antes da comparação. No seu repositório crie um método parecido com isso

```
// Em MySQL, por usar uma raw
public function findByBatata($type, $date, $format = '%Y-%m') {
    return $this->model
         ->where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '$format')", '=', $date))
         ->where('type', '=', $type)
         ->get();
}

// Em Postgresql
public function findByBatata($type, $date, $format = 'YYYY-MM') {
    return $this->model
         ->where(\DB::raw("to_char(`date`, '$format')", '=', $date))
         ->where('type', '=', $type)
         ->get();
}
```

Isso pode não ser muito performático pois não serão considerados os índices nesse campo.

Como apontado em outra resposta, é possível usar um *range* de datas. O Eloquent tem o método `whereBetween` para isso:

```
public function findByBatata($type, $date, $format = 'Y-m') {
    // Considerando data no formato 2016-02
    $dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);

    // o primeiro dia do mês hard coded
    $dateStart = $dateTime->format('Y-m-01');

    // t é equivalente ao último dia do mês
    $dateEnd = $dateTime->format('Y-m-t');

    return $this->model
         ->whereBetween('date', [$dateStart, $dateEnd])
         ->where('type', '=', $type)
         ->get();
}
```

Outra opção é duplicar esse campo já formato no formato mês e ano, inserir um índice e pesquisar diretamente por esse novo campo.

Comment: esse "\DateTime::dateFromFormat" não é encontrado aqui, da esse erro: "Call to undefined method DateTime::dateFromFormat()". de onde importo isso? @gmsantos

Comment: @RaylanSoares falha minha, isso que dá fazer código aqui direto na resposta :)

Comment: Obrigado, consegui solucionar adaptando sua segunda sugestão =)

Comment: Para o downvote: onde posso melhorar ?

Answer (score -1):

E como a data esta armazenada? Por que o mesmo erro deveria ocorrer também no INSERT correto? Como esta a modelagem do banco? O campo `date` é do tipo DATE ou VARCHAR?

Acredito em 2 possibilidades.

1 - Fazer a busca com um range com inicio e fim do mês, mas ai depende de como estão os dados no banco.

```
$date = date('Y-m'); //so exemplo para ficar o ano e mes atual

//precisa adicioanr o range dos dias
$dateStart = date($date.'-01');
$dateEnd = date($date.'-t'); //o t pega o maximo de dias do mes

//ai é so fazer a busca pelo intervalo do mes com base nos daias
echo 'SELECT * FROM "values" WHERE "type" = "Receita" AND (date >= '.$dateStart.' AND date <= '.$dateEnd.' )';
```

O resultado vai ser algo o tipo

```
SELECT * FROM "values" WHERE "type" = "Receita" AND (date >= 2016-09-01 AND date <= 2016-09-30
```

Ai é só adaptar para a query do laravel.

2 - Mudar o banco e colocar dois campos na tabela, `year VARCHAR(4)` e `month VARCHAR(2)` ao invés de só 1 do tipo `date` e talvez seja mais fácil manipular os dados assim.

Comment: Não recomendo o item 2. Melhor duplicar as colunas com a data já formatada do que substituir a coluna do tipo date.

Comment: Outro ponto, o `$dateEnd` não vai funcionar corretamente.